# Google Auth token expires and cant refresh with PHP API Auth client?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am using the latest found at [Google PHP API library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)

Authentication started on iOS->get code->send to server->get token all works well. But I Store the token for user locally on the server to be used on behalf of iOS client offline access.

Note: $googleToken contains refresh token as well.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$client->setApplicationName('MyServer');
$client->setClientId($google_config["clientId"]);
$client->setClientSecret($google_config["clientSecret"]);
$client->setRedirectUri("");
$client->setDeveloperKey($google_config["developerKey"]);

$googleToken = getGoogleToken($user);  //locally stored google token for user
$client->setAccessToken($googleToken['token']);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
StoreToken($access_token);
```

and store access_token again. When it expires though my calls start to fail:

> "error" : "invalid_request",  "error_description" : "Client must
>   specify either client_id or client_assertion, not both"

I have tried `setRefreshToken` and every other combination and still can not get it to work.
What am I doing wrong? I did try to set state offline but not sure if it even matters since I get refresh token as part of initial token.

Answer (score 2):

Wow.. figured it out. It was actually my own problem. $google_config is a global defined in config file! and I was missing `global $google_config;` in the function! as result client_id and secret_id were both missing - The error message though is incorrect to say the least!